# Graph to draw community structure with graph-tool

Tags: python, graph-tool, network-analysis

I need to draw community structure of a brain network. Similar to the attached images. I am using graph-tool python tool box. Any help to create this would be highly appreciated.

[image: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19027073].
[image: http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fnins.2016.00394/full]

Comment: Have you looked into Anaconda?

Comment: I use graph-tool to perform my analysis sand get the community structure using the stochastic_block_models in graph-tool. I just need help in using the graph-tool's draw functionalities to get figures similar to above.

Comment: If you have found the answer useful, please accept it by clicking the mark near it.

Answer (score 1):

So if `G` is your graph, you can fit standard stochastic block model (i.e. the one without degree corrections) to obtain the community structure as:

```
state = gt.minimize_blockmodel_dl(G, deg_corr=False)
```

After this, you can use `draw` method which is simply a wrapper to the `graph_draw()` as:

```
state.draw(pos=g.vp.pos, output="my_graph.pdf")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
vprop_int = g.new_vertex_property("int")
vprop[g1.vertex(0)] = 5
...
```

then you will get property for all vertice
in your case, you might assign different number
then when you are drawing

```
graph_draw(g, vertex_text=g.vertex_index, vertex_font_size=80
           , vertex_fill_color=vprop_int
           , edge_pen_width=20, edge_color=eprop_int
           , output_size=(20000, 20000), output="test.png")
```

the part you decide the color of vertice
i put

```
vertex_fill_color=vprop_int
```

I hope this will help